# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): array::at: __n (which is 1990878449) >= _Nm (which is 5)

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

```
 array<int,5> ar3;
  for(auto i : ar3){
    ar3.at(i) = i+1;
    cout<<ar3.at(i)<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
```

The above is the piece of code that I run and the following error popped up

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  array::at: __n (which is 1990878449) >= _Nm (which is 5)**

What am I missing/going wrong on?

Thanks

Comment: A range loop iterates over elements, not indices.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` is a plain aggregate, when you declare an instance like this,

```
std::array<int, 5> a;
```

it does *not* initialize any of its member values. Hence, all `int`s in the array contain some random garbage values. Next, you iterate over the *values* of the array,

```
for (auto i : a) { /* .. */ }
```

The loop variable `i` will hold these garbage values during the iteration, one at a time, until accessing the array out of bounds with

```
ar.at(i) // again: i can be anything
```

It seems that what you want to do is having `i` increase from zero to `size - 1`. Use a good old `for` loop for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar3.size(); ++i)
{
    ar3.at(i) = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```cpp
for (auto i : ar3)
```

it's like:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < ar3.size(); x++) {
    i = ar3.at(x);
    // here the for (auto i : ar3) start
}
```

But you didn't initialise the value of `ar3` so you have random number in it. So in your loop you try to access random case of your `array`.
To fix that you can initialise your array or don't use `for (auto i : ar3)` but:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < ar3.size(); i++) {
    ar3.at() = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: typo: `ar3.at()`

Answer (score 0):

From [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

> default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T)

This is indeed what happens for `int` and reading these values makes your program have undefined behavior.

If your aim is to fill the `std::array` with the values 1-5, you could instead use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota):

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric> // std::iota

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> ar3;
    std::iota(ar3.begin(), ar3.end(), 1); // start at 1
}
```